# How to remove duplicate records by column (Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've done something similar using Teradata as a backend and ROWS OVER/PARTITION but I've never had to try and replicate this in access. I have a simple query I'm trying to execute.

```
SELECT DISTINCT extract_office.dos, 
extract_office.Patient_ID, 
extract_office.cpt5

FROM extract_office
order by dos
;
```

This returns data as follows:

```
dos      Patient_ID cpt5
7/31/2013   98521   93880
7/31/2013   98521   93923
7/31/2013   98521   93926
8/7/2013    93600   76536
8/7/2013    93600   99213
9/30/2013   66859   93926
9/30/2013   66859   99212
9/30/2013   70265   99024
9/30/2013   72977   99204
```

I would like this to return just 5 rows, one for 7/31/2013 one for 8/7/2013, and 3 unique (based on Patient_id) rows from 9/30/2013 (values 66859,70265,72977)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So are you wanting to exclude the values in cpt5? or are you wanting to pivot those into other columns?

Comment: I'd like to exclude the values in cpt5

Comment: Ahhh, so if i just don't include the column in my select i should be all set huh?

Comment: Yes, if you exclude the column, it wont worry about the distinct records for that column.  If you need to see those values, you can join them back up in a subselect.. tho.. that probably doesnt make sense w/ what you're doing here.

Comment: Perfect! thank you for helping me think this through!

Comment: Happy to help, glad you got it working. have a +1

Answer (score 2):

Needed to exclude cpt5 column!

```
SELECT DISTINCT extract_office.dos, 
extract_office.Patient_ID, 

FROM extract_office
order by dos
;
```